# How to find long/lat (in Python) from a GeoTIFF that does not have CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude

I have a GeoTIFF file that in Python the dimension is (9991,10439). I need to know the long/lat information for each pixel but the problem is the CRS is None for this file and when I try to create a new GeoTIFF file with CRS (using the below code), the new GeoTIFF file has a different dimension of (4177,14274). I opened the original GeoTIFF file in QGIS and realized that the dimension is (4177,14274). I understand that this mismatch is coming from the black border in the image (please see attached) but for the purpose of my work, I need the long/lat with the same size as the original file when I open it in Python (9991,10439). But how?

Here is the link to the original file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HrKMmP1f9GP1A3lthfrXFTADGWnvlhUN/view?usp=sharing
and new file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKgwHKcQDXXcUJDuPNuM55qYrfBbZKoJ/view?usp=sharing

```py
from osgeo import gdal
raster = gdal.Open('original.tiff')
raster_data = raster.ReadAsArray()
raster_data.shape # (9991, 10439)
gdal.Warp('new.tiff', 'original.tiff', dstSRS='EPSG: 4326')
raster_new = gdal.Open('new.tiff')
raster_new_data = raster_new.ReadAsArray()
raster_new_data.shape # (4177, 14274)
```

Comment: Is there any georeferencing? That is, if you query the header and/or extent are there 'real' coordinate values or do you get the raw cell numbers? If the former, please edit them into the question.

Comment: The original CRS for georeferencing is 'EPSG: 4326', but in Python it is none. I need the real coordinate values (in degree), so I created a "new.tiff" and defined the CRS. But the dimension is the issue. To clarify the problem, I need to be able to remove/exclude nan values (values around the edge of the image) from the "new.tiff" so that I can get the original size I'm looking for (9991, 10439).